# Extract iodine from tincture?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, extraction

What I am trying to do is extract elemental iodine from iodine tincture - that is 5% iodine solution in aqueous ethanol with $\ce{KI}$ as "helper additive", or whatever you'd call it. I don't have povidone-iodine, I don't have iodide tincture, and I don't have $\ce{KI}$. Well, there is $\ce{KI}$ in my tincture, but that is not my point. My point is, there are procedures for extracting $\ce{I2}$ from povidone-iodine, there are procedures for converting iodide salts (in tincture or not) to elemental iodine, and there are those for simply precipitating out $\ce{I_2}$ from tincture, which is my case.

BTW why not just evaporate the ethanol, or is the iodine too volatile - will sublimate with the evaporating ethanol(iodine sublimates at $\ce{113.7 ^\circ C}$)?

I want to use household vinegar - 6% apple vinegar if possible because it is easily available. Also, I want to use 3% pharmacy grade $\ce{H2O2}$ for the same reasons.

I have done this, kind of successfully, but I want to know what is the chemistry behind all that, and how would you calculate the amounts of reagents needed?

Comment: Where do the vinegar and the H2O2 come in? What is the point in all this? And what kind of equipment do you have? How *did* you extract the iodine, if you already managed to do so?

Comment: Keep in mind that Iodine is a restricted substance. Trying to isolate iodine from iodine tincture raise a question.

Comment: @Karl I have equipment and acetic acid and I have elemental iodine. The point is doing the extraction without equipment, so I can document the whole process. This is what I am asking precisely, where does the acid and H2O2 come in, because I know the procedure works and has been documented, the problem is, they don't explain the reaction mechanism or give quantities.

Comment: @Mathew Mahindaratne Wander what this question is... Iodine is not restricted here, you should not assume anyone lives in the US

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to save the iodine $\ce{I_2}$ from its solution, you may add enough $\ce{KOH}$ or $\ce{NaOH}$ in the mixture to transform all $\ce{I_2}$ into a colorless mixture of $\ce{KI}$ and $\ce{KIO_3}$. $$\ce{3I_2  +  6OH^- -> IO_3^- + 5I^- + 3H_2O}$$The remaining ethanol can then be evaporated by heating the nearly colorless solution to a temperature higher than $80$°C. When the temperature reaches $100$°C, the ethanol is totally removed from the solution : the hot solution can be cooled down to room temperature, and some acid should be added in order to destroy the excess of $\ce{NaOH}$ ou $\ce{KOH}$, and then to recover the iodine $\ce{I_2}$ according to $$\ce{IO_3^- + 5 I^- + 6 H^+ -> 3 I_2 + 3 H_2O}$$ The totality of the iodine $\ce{I_2}$ dissolved in the original tincture is recovered, without any amount of ethanol, and can be saved by filtration.